# Hexdump binary file while honoring separators

Tags: files, hexdump

I have a binary file where records are separated by newlines. `hexdump` just dumps everything with a fixed column width. Is there a tool to hexdump this file, while honoring the newline separator? (Any other separator, like `0`, would also be fine.)

Comment: That sounds a bit weird. I'm assuming this file is created by a Unix / Linux system, so the newline is `\n` = `\x0a`. Does the actual record data contain all other possible byte values, or is it restricted somehow? I suppose you'd like the hexdump output to be line by line, matching the binary data. Do you just want to see the hex data, or would you like output similar to the default output of either the hexdump or the hd programs?

Answer (score 0):

This Python script will do it, sort of:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(mode='rb'):
    print(line)
```

There's one problem that I hadn't realized: the binary data may itself contain the separator character, messing up the output.

Comment: In what sense is that a hexdump? Maybe you meant `print(line.encode('hex'))` or something...

Comment: It's a hexdump because the input is read in binary mode (`'rb'`).

Comment: Ah, no. That's _not_ what's normally meant by the term [hexdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump).

Comment: You are right. `print` will try to interpret as UTF-8. A lot of characters in my data then print like this `\xc8\x02\x00`, which at first glance looks like a hexdump. However, it's Python's way of saying that these are non-printable characters.